# Passing a model instance to a helper method in rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a helper method in my app located in `spec/support/utilities.rb`
I am trying to pass an instance of a model object to it but I haven't succeeded so the tests fail

here is the helper method

```
def attribute_not_present(model_instance,model_attrib)
  describe "when #{model_attrib} is not present" do
    before { model_instance.send("#{model_attrib}=", " ") }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
 end
```

in `spec/model/tool_spec.rb` i have this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Tool do
  before do
    @tool = FactoryGirl.create(:tool)    
  end

  @attribute_array = ["kind", "serial_number", "department", "size", 
  "description", "hours", "length"] 

  subject { @tool }  

  #checks for absence of any of the required attributes
  @attribute_array.each { |tool_attribute|
    attribute_not_present(@tool,tool_attribute)
  } 
end
```

the `@tool` seems not to be recognized in the helper

the sample failure is this

```
1) Tool when size is not present 
  Failure/Error: before { model_instance.send("#{model_attrib}=", " ") }
  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `size=' for nil:NilClass
  # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in attribute_not_present'
```

I am rails newbie

Comment: This looks a little bit like you are reinventing shared examples

Comment: not really am doing using Rpsec programmatically where by I avoiding the same kind of code. am DRYing up the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point where `attribute_not_present` is called, @tool does not yet exist. Moreover, in one case `self` is the example group, where when the spec is actually run (and inside your before blocks) self is an instance of the example group.

You don't need to pass `model_instance` through at all though - you could instead just use `subject` i.e.

```
before { subject.send("#{model_attrib}=", " ") }
```

however.

You may also want to look at shared examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I think I understand what you're trying to do here.  You're trying to do unit tests, specifically validations on your Tool class, is that right?

If so, I personally like to use the [shoulda_matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem which I find to be very idiomatic with exactly this.

As an example, you could do:

```
describe Tool do 
  it { should validate_presence_of(:kind) }
  it { should validate_presnece_of(:serial_number) }
end
```

You can even do more with the validations, say you knew the `:serial_number` can only be an integer, you could do:

```
it { should validate_numericality_of(:serial_number).only_integer }
```

This is probably a better way to do unit level validations than a helper method as it's more Ruby-like.